# SSH and remote desktop access over WAN lost after long idle pause overnigth on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, server, wireless, suspend, 21.04

For two nights in a row I lost access to an Ubuntu machine that I plan to use for remote control of an experiment.

- I'm running Ubuntu 21.04
- The hardware is a [Minisforum GK41](https://store.minisforum.com/pages/product)
- It's currently using WAN at home, on the local network. After I reboot it because connection is lost, the IP stays the same.
- Both SSH and Nomachine server access lost and don't seem to recover by just waiting
- I tried disabling sleep, suspend etc... :
  sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

I'm not sure what is causing that. If the issue is due to WAN only and would not happen on cable, then I'm happy to just ignore the issue but the fact that the access never recover is worrying me.

I have a [log](https://pastebin.com/ESSdGPez), but cannot find an obvious issue in it. The issue happened between ~6:00 and 13:00. I tried to login at ~13:30 and rebooted at 13:36.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have loss of SSH connectivity issues often for devices on the WiFi portion of my LAN, but never for non WiFi devices on my LAN.

Comment: @DougSmythies Ok, thanks. I may just let it run on cable and do a test for 24h, but I really don't want to have to go on site and reboot it every day or so...

Comment: No issues so far on cabled LAN, after 48h remote operation. I'm still curious why is the WAN not recovering. SSH server over WAN works well on raspberry Pis over long period of time...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Interesting, because it is raspberry Pis I am having the most troubles with. I didn't used to, once I set wlan0 power_save to off, but have ever since recent updates. I have 3 on WiFi and 1 wired. Note "WAN" means Wide Area Network, i.e. internet not WiFi LAN.